# Regex to match comma separated values INV-x,INV-y,INV-z etc.?

Tags: regex

I am not very good with regex and was wondering if someone could help me write a regex for this string:

```
INV-6001,INV-5067,INV-6795
```

INV- is always the same, then followed by four digits (this may grow to five or six or more).

They can be infinitely separated by commas.

How would i write something like this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if you can point me in the direction of a generator where i can paste this into and it will spit out the expression for me.

Cheers

Comment: What is "valid" input and what is "invalid" input? Some answers "work", but likely don't cover the expected cases: using regular expressions is all about *defining a precise set of rules*. Once you have defined these you will be able to update your title/question with something more focused and relevant.

Comment: Valid is:
INV- <---this to be fixed (cannot be anything different)

It will always be followed by digits and can be separated with a comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires at least one `INV-` section. It will not accept leading or trailing commas. It only accepts 4 (or 5 or 6) digits. (The previous statements assume it is anchored to the ends.)

```
INV-\d{4,6}(?:,INV-\d{4,6})*
```

Alternatively, and perhaps more advisable (as regular expressions can become over-complicated quickly!), is to *split* the input on "," and then ensure that each section conforms to `INV-\d{4,6}` in a loop. If something needs to done with the data *anyway*, then the "code overhead" for the partial-regex approach becomes minimal.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(,\1)+(?=,|$)
```

[Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/regexbuddy/duplicatecsv.html)

Comment: This will match `X,X,X` but not `X,Y,Z`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this regex would solve your problem: `/[^,]+/g`